# how to find Profile module

Tags: users

I cannot find Profile module in the core in drupal7, I want to create a registration page with multiple textboxes. Kindly tell how can I find the profile module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Profile 2 module isn't in Drupal 7 core yet. You can download it [here](https://drupal.org/project/profile2).

If you'd like to set up user profiles without Profile 2, you can add more fields to the user profile at **Administration > Configuration > People > Account Settings > Manage Fields** and play around with [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) and [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) afterwards.

You can find more information here too:

- [How can I create user profiles in drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14905/how-can-i-create-user-profiles-in-drupal-7)
- [How to create a profile page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88407/how-to-create-a-profile-page)

Answer (score 0):

Administration -> Configuration -> People -> Account Settings -> Manage Fields

or in in the URL:

`admin/config/people/accounts/fields`

You should better read some documentation before asking such basic topics to community.

Comment: Cannot find Profile module even in: admin/config/people/accounts/fields

Comment: If you cannot see the manage fields under "Accounts settings.." as described above, please make sure you have "Field UI" module enabled (this actually might be the piece you are missing)